# How do I seal in/deal with shower drain in foundation?

Tags: shower, drain

How would I seal in this shower drain?

here is the abs drain out and in and I'm wondering if:

- I even need to seal it
- concrete
- silicone?

[image]

[image]

Comment: So your shower floor is the foundation?

Comment: no. there is a short subfloor, resting on 2x4s then 3/4 plywood. that's how it was when we moved in. I'm fixing some rot.

Comment: There's no plumbing in the concrete?

Comment: not sure, can't see that far. It looks like just a straight concrete tube

Comment: The drain fitting is supposed to fit onto a drain pipe leading down to a trap. All I see in the photo looks like concrete formed against the drain fitting -- no pipe. This doesn't look right.